# Can I use ILogger<T> with Enterprise Library Logging?

Tags: logging, .net-core, migration, enterprise-library

I'm migrating an application into an existing .net core application. The existing application uses ILogger<> for logging while the migrating application uses Enterprise Library.

Can these co-exists? can I turn Enterprise Library into into an ILogger writer?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any nuget packages out of the box that would link up Enterprise Library to ILogger.

You might have to create your own ILoggerProvider that would write to Enterprise Library.

Here are some blogs that could help you

https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/05/05/add-custom-logging-in-aspnetcore.html
https://andrewlock.net/creating-a-rolling-file-logging-provider-for-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: actually i want to do the reverse. use EL to output to the same defined destinations as LoggerFactory providers